# bash script truncates file on CentOS 5.5

Tags: bash

The scenario is as follows

I create a file test.txt in /home/raveen with the contents below

```
FRUITS = apple guava banana
VEGETABLES = turnip onion spinach
```

I write a script test.sh with the contents below

```
echo "FLOWERS = dahlia rose jasmine" >> /home/raveen/test.txt
```

After executing this "bash" script the file gets truncated and only the contents

```
FLOWERS = dahlia rose jasmine
```

appears the file test.txt

Does anyone know the reason for this? Has anyone seen such a problem before?

Comment: Please, could you post your bash code?

Comment: This is the behavior you would get if the file you created in 1. was not named exactly "test.txt" or was not exactly in /home/raveen.

Comment: recheck and 100% ensure is `>>`

Comment: Hi Simone, Pascal and Ajreal,

     I was able to reproduce this problem with a simple file called "test.txt" as mentioned earlier. This was on CentOS 5.5 and I had done this with just one line in a file called "test.sh". The line was

echo "FLOWERS = dahlia rose jasmine" >> /home/raveen/test.txt

Never mind, the actual use case was, I had a simple shell script "test.sh" with the contents

echo "cp:5:respawn:/home/raveen/notify" >> /etc/inittab

and I was running test.sh as "root"

/etc/inittab was getting truncated as well.

Regards
Raveendran V.

Comment: Is it bash? Or do you have #!/bin/sh as the first line?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your code, but I can guarantee that the following would work.

```
cat | tee /home/raveen/test.txt <<EOF
FRUITS = apple guava banana
VEGETABLES = turnip onion spinach
EOF

echo 'FLOWERS = dahlia rose jasmine' | tee -a /home/raveen/test.txt
```

I prefer using `tee` because something like: `sed 's/a/e/g' test.txt > test.txt` wouldn't work because bash opens test.txt before you execute the command, so you would end up with an empty file, whereas `sed 's/a/e/g' test.txt | tee -a >/dev/null test.txt` would work fine. Also you can silence tee by using `>/dev/null`, I personally use `alias stee="tee >/dev/null"`.